# Share LESS variables/mixins without duplicating between multiple files in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, less

Rails asset pipeline compiles all my LESS files (including Bootstrap variables, mixins, etc.) to one single stylesheet. The problem is the output CSS is getting bigger and bigger and lots of styles are only specific to only one page. I want to load those styles only for that page.

So I make the layout to load application.less and also a page specific stylesheet. I @import all the Boostrap LESS files in application.less. But I also want to use some variables/mixins from Bootstrap in my page specific stylesheet. So I have to @import again the Bootstrap files in my page specific stylesheet, which I already have in application.less. Bootstrap is duplicate now.

What's the best way to go around this problem? I tried to use reference import `@import (reference) "bootstrap.less";` but I get Less error: `expected ')' got 'r'`.

I'm using `less (2.4.0, 2.3.2)` and `less-rails (2.4.2, 2.3.3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay! less.rb has been updated to 2.5.0 with support of less 1.6.2 a few hours ago.

https://github.com/cowboyd/less.rb/blob/master/Changelog.md

Answer (score 0):

You have done things correctly, but your issue is the version of less you are using.

[According to the LESS 2.4.0 release for Ruby](https://github.com/cowboyd/less.rb/blob/master/Changelog.md), it is running LESS version 1.4.2. However, the `(reference)` option was not added [until LESS version 1.5.0](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-reference), so it is not implemented yet.

This is almost certainly why it is giving you your error of `expected ')' got 'r'`, as it does not know how to handle the `(reference)` import option.

Comment: What are my options here? Is it possible to upgrade LESS.rb to use LESS 1.5+ manually?

Comment: I do not know the answer to that.

Comment: less.rb has just been updated! I've added my own answer. Thanks @ScottS.